# Android: go back to previous activity?

Tags: android

Is there a way I can force the user to go back to the previous Activity? I'd like to kill my current Activity make the user "go back" possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call finish in your Activity : http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

And to make sure you started your activity correctly to have the state in the Activity Stack, check the documentation there : http://d.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 6):

Call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

**From the link**:  Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

Answer (score 5):

Call `finish()` to end the current activity and go back.